# Can I declare attributes with function object in one statement

Tags: javascript

For an object `obj`, I can define the following two-line statements

```
 var obj ={} //this is an object
    obj.isShiny = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
    };
```

as one-line statement

```
var obj={
        isShiny : function () {
            console.log(this);
            return "you bet1";
        }
};
```

For a function `func` with two-line statements as follows

```
 var func = function () {console.log(this)}; //this is a function
    func.isShiny = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
    };
```

Is it possible to merge it into one-line statement?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to merge it into one-line statement?

Not in the way you mean, no.

You could do it literally in *one line*, but not in a single statement/expression.

You could have just one *outermost* statement/expression, but I can't imagine that's what you meant:

```
var func = (function() {
    function func() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    func.isShiny = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
    };
    return func;
})();
```

There's little call for that, maybe if you had to fill in something where you only got a single expression to fill in (perhaps as part of a property initializer on a larger object).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var func = Object.assign(
    function() {console.log(this)},
    {
      isShiny: function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer :)

```
 if (typeof Function.prototype.method !== "function") {
            Function.prototype.method = function (name, implementation) {
                this[name] = implementation;
                return this;
            };
        }


        var func =
                function () {console.log(this)}.method
                ("isShiny",function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    return "you bet1";
                });//this is a function


        console.log(func.isShiny());
```